# Is there a good line graph API out there with my specifications?

Tags: javascript, flash, html

I have data whose primary visual representation is a simple number as aline height, but the rest of the data for a single sample contains much more data. I want to convey this extra information on a html5/flash line graph where each example is guaranteed to be on a single tick, and that the control can drive a click event that supplies the closest tick near the click and the entire associated sample data.

For example:

```
data = [
   {number: 1, extradata : {...}},
   {number: 2, extradata : {...}},
   {number: 3, extradata : {...}},
]
```

The graph would have at least 3 ticks, and if the user hovers/clicks, the extra data of the nearest tick would be shown elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) springs to mind...

All done with script and SVG tho, no flash afaik